# python2.6 import error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i am porting my python script written on 3 to 2.6 and i am getting below errors and i could not find out the equivalent imports.

```
import win32com.client
from Tkinter import FileDialog
```

How to fix these issues ?

Using Python 2.6.5

Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

```
****************************************************************
Personal firewall software may warn about the connection IDLE
makes to its subprocess using this computer's internal loopback
interface.  This connection is not visible on any external
interface and no data is sent to or received from the Internet.
****************************************************************
```

IDLE 2.6.5      ==== No Subprocess ====

Thanks You

Comment: what ? I dont understand the question?

Comment: i am getting import error for import win32com.client
from Tkinter import FileDialog 

Error : ImportError: No module named...

Comment: install those modules for 2.6?

Comment: i could not find FileDialog module for 2.6

Comment: from Tkinter import FileDialog  is my import statement and when i execute i get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Squish\Run_Test.py", line 23, in <module>
    from Tkinter import FileDialog
ImportError: cannot import name FileDialog

Comment: `import tkFileDialog as FileDialog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The win32com module is not included with Python, you need to install it.
The tk filedialog is in tkFileDialog.

See also [Reorganizations and renamings chapter](http://python3porting.com/stdlib.html?highlight=tkfiledialog) from [the book](http://python3porting.com).